# HTML5 video and audio don't play in all (mobile) browsers

Tags: iphone, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I am using HTML5 tags to call audio(mp3) and video(mp4) files which also have to work in ios platform like iPhone/iPod/iPad etc...(I am not sure it will support or not please, give me alternate option if MP3 and MP4 dose not work in ios platform.)

Video work fine in all browser but not in firefox, but audio does not work any browser.

you will find code from below demo link but I have not given live path for audio and video as its confidential but you will get idea in case if I am using wrong path or any missing tags here.

demo [link](http://jsfiddle.net/avcreative/rJBrC/)

Answer (score 0):

The demo link is useless without absolute links to video and audio files in the question.

Your audio and video encoding are most likely wrong. However, helping with this is impossible without having the actual files in the question.

For supported audio and video formats please read:

http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html

Comment: can you guide me that how to call mp3 and mp4 files with <audio> <video> html5 tags which work also fine in ios?

Comment: No. As it is mostly likely matter with the source material encoding, not HTML syntax. If I have no idea what kind of material you are feeding for the tags and why there is no way I could help you. I can only point you to relevant tutorials how to encode video and audio, but you could find those in Google yourself.

Comment: Have already mention for video I used <video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
      <source src="files/789.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>  which is not work in firefox 15

Comment: and for audio <audio controls="controls">
   <source src="files/456.mp3" src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio> which only work in IE

Comment: You have not mentioned how you create these video files or somehow I am blind. Please tell in the questions why you are trying something and what you have done this far. Using video encoding tools you should be able to produce compliant files, but because you don't tell what tools you are using and how it is little bit difficult to start guess why the system we have no access does not work.

Comment: I got few files(MP3 and MP4) from my client which he want to add in his website and I simply encode with HTML5 tags.

Comment: Please read the full link I pasted in the answer, so that you understand what's encoding is all about http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#miro - probably your client has supplied bad files for you.

Comment: okay I got it for Firefox and Opera I need to add other supported file as mention in http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/#media_formats

Answer (score 0):

So here is conclusion if we are using html5 tags for audio/video we need to take appropriate files as per the browser. like Firefox dose not support mp4 for that we require WebM and for audio Vorbis but not mp3.